# Author list goes outside margins in the ACM SIGCHI template

Tags: margins, titles, templates

For some reason having 4 authors in this ACM SIGCHI template renders it outside the right margin. [See more details and image here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/285483/tmp/chi2011latex/index.html).

I suspect the problem is with .cls but I have no idea where to start. Here are the relevant lines in the .tex source:

```
\numberofauthors{4}
\author{
  \alignauthor Aaaaa Aaaaaaa\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@a.com}
  \alignauthor Bbbbbbb Bbbbbb\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@b.com}
  \alignauthor Cccccc Cccccc\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@c.com}
  \alignauthor Ddddddd Dddddddd\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@d.com}
}

\maketitle
```

Comment: The link to the `cls` file in your link is broken.

Comment: fixed. sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the template is the same as what you can get from http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates then have a look at question 18 in their [FAQ](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq) (scroll, don't click).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. I should have Googled more.

Comment: The links are no more valid.

Answer (score 3):

[This template on the ACM website](https://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigproc-sp.tex) says to use `\and` every three authors and to have a maximum of 2 rows. If you have more than 6 authors, *then* use `\additionalauthors`. For example:

```
\numberofauthors{8}
\author{
       \alignauthor{First Author\titlenote{Additional Notes about the author},\\
              \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
              \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
              \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
              \email{trovato@corporation.com}}
       }
       \alignauthor
       Second Author, \\
              \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
              \affaddr{P.O. Box 1212}\\
              \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}\\
              \email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
       % 3rd. author
       \alignauthor Third Author\\
              \affaddr{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}\\
              \affaddr{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}\\
              \affaddr{Hekla, Iceland}\\
              \email{larst@affiliation.org}
\and
       \alignauthor Fourth Author\\
              \affaddr{Brookhaven Laboratories}\\
              \affaddr{Brookhaven National Lab}\\
              \affaddr{P.O. Box 5000}\\
              \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
       \alignauthor Fifth Author\\
              \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
              \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
              \affaddr{California 94035}\\
              \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
       \alignauthor Sixth Author\\
              \affaddr{Palmer Research Laboratories}\\
              \affaddr{8600 Datapoint Drive}\\
              \affaddr{San Antonio, Texas 78229}\\
              \email{cpalmer@prl.com}
       }
\additionalauthors{Additional authors: Seventh Author (The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group,
email: {\texttt{jsmith@affiliation.org}}), and Eighth Author
(The Kumquat Consortium, email: {\texttt{jpkumquat@consortium.net}}).}
```

And [this is how the template looks compiled](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/sig-alternate-sample.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The class seems explicitly set up for maximum 3 authors. For more than 3 it seems to want you to do something like:

```
\numberofauthors{5}
\author{
  \alignauthor Author 1\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author@a.com}
  \alignauthor Author 2\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author2@b.com}
  \alignauthor Author 3\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \email{author2@b.com}}
\additionalauthors{Author 4, Author 5}
```

Which puts an "additional authors" section at the end, before the references...

Comment: Thanks Lev. I hadn't noticed that. Unfortunately, since most people use the MS Word template, putting additional authors at the end is very uncommon (couldn't find any example in the 2010 proceedings for example).